# issue with Cocoapods and hermes-engine

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

currenty I'm using pod@1.15.0 to install hermes-engine (0.72.6)

the cocoapods is from brew,I'm getting the error

```
[!] Error installing hermes-engine
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an issue with pod@1.15.0 so I downgraded it to pod@1.14.3 and it's working as expected now

One way to fetch a specific version is as follows:

First, you'll probably want to uninstall cocoapods:

`brew uninstall cocoapods`

Find a suitable cocoapods.rb e.g. by browsing the repo -> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/6b1477715df13e0ec4305c3420ac0c024867d34a/Formula/c/cocoapods.rb

For cocoapods 1.14.3:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/6b1477715df13e0ec4305c3420ac0c024867d34a/Formula/c/cocoapods.rb  # or just download it 

brew install -s cocoapods.rb
```

Comment: Wow thank you for this, I struggled thru hours of trying to get Hermes to build using cocoapods 1.15.0. For me I wasn't using brew, I just used the gem. So what worked for me was:

gem uninstall cocoa pods, 

gem install cocoa pods -v 1.14.3, 

rm -rf Pods, 
rm Podfile.lock, 

pod install, 

And finally I have liftoff. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated React Native to 0.73.4 and Cocapod to 1.15.2 and it has been fixed.

Comment: How do you set the version of Cocoapods in a CI environment like AppCenter?

Or simply using RN 0.73.4 installs the latest Cocoapods? I am getting the build to work locally. But still failing in AppCenter?

Comment: Hi, I was using Azure Devops and I run the script to install Cocapod 1.15.2

Comment: Can you give us the script you're using ?

Comment: Here it is:   sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.15.2